# Inequality related to $\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=i+1}^{m} \left\Vert a_{i}+a_{j}\right\Vert$

Tags: inequality, summation, vectors, analytic-geometry

Given vectors $a_{i} \in \mathbb R^3$ ,where $i$ is a natural number satisfying $1\le i\le 3$, then the following relation does hold:
$$\left\Vert a_1+a_2\right\Vert+\left\Vert a_1+a_3\right\Vert+\left\Vert a_2+a_3\right\Vert\le\left\Vert a_1\right\Vert+\left\Vert a\right\Vert+\left\Vert a_3\right\Vert+\left\Vert a_1+a_2+a_3\right\Vert$$

---

I Tried to generalized the problem:
Given vectors $a_{i} \in \mathbb R^n$ ,where $i$ is a natural number satisfying $1\le i\le m$,then the following relation does hold:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=i+1}^{m} \left\Vert a_{i}+a_{j}\right\Vert \le\sum_{i=1}^{m} \left\Vert a_{i} \right\Vert+ \left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}\right\Vert$$

Is the generalization true?if yes then how to prove that?

Comment: If there is a generalization, it would be something like $$\sum_{|S|\text{ even}}\left\|\sum_{i\in S}a_i\right\|\leq \sum_{|S|\text{ odd}}\left\|\sum_{i\in S}a_i\right\|$$  I don't know if it's true, but it passes the simple combinatorial test in the answer someone gave below.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Let $a_i=a\neq 0$ for all $i$.  Then LHS is $m(m-1)\lVert a\rVert$ and RHS is $2m\lVert a\rVert$, so LHS is larger than RHS for sufficiently large $m$.

Comment: Every $m\geq 4$ would do.  Note that since each $a_i$ are equal, you just count the number of terms in the sum.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as *Hlawka's inequality*. It can be written as
$$\mathbb E\left\|\sum_{i=1}^3\epsilon_ix_i\right\|\ge\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^3\|x_i\|$$
where $x_i=\frac{a_i+a_{i+1}}{2}$ (with $a_4=a_1$) and the $\epsilon_i$s are i.i.d. random variables such that $\epsilon_i=\pm1$ with probability $\frac12$. According to Honda *et al.*, [*Generalizations of the Hlawka's Inequality*](http://macaron.ces.kyutech.ac.jp/honda/honda/publication/files/1998GeneralizationHlawkaInequality.pdf), Bull. Kyushu Inst. Tech., Pure Appl. Math., no. 45, 1998, pp.9-15, it has the generalization
$$\mathbb E\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_ix_i\right\|\ge\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\binom{n-1}{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\sum_{i=1}^n\|x_i\|$$
(where $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ are any $n$ vectors in an inner product space) and this inequality is tight. When $n=4$, if I am not mistaken, by setting $x_i=\frac{a_i+a_{i+1}}{2}$ (with $a_{n+1}=a_1$) the inequality can be simplified to
\begin{aligned}
&\|a_1+a_2\|+\|a_2+a_3\|+\|a_3+a_4\|+\|a_4+a_1\|\\
\le\ &2\left(\|a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4\|+\|a_1-a_3\|+\|a_2-a_4\|\right).
\end{aligned}